# StreamReader and StreamWriter on the same Stream?

Tags: c#, stream

How do I manage closing `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter` which are using the same underlying stream?

```
var stream = /*...*/;
var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
var writer = new StreamWRiter(stream);
```

I know that I could simply ignore closing the reader/writer and just close the underlying stream. However, that seems a bit of a hack, since it is based on the **assumption** that the reader/writer doesn't have anything to dispose (which might not be the case in the future).

I know this have been solved in .NET 4.5 with an extra constructor argument, but until .NET 4.5 is released, how do I solve it in a proper way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you `Flush()` the writer first.

And then just Dispose or Close the 2 decorators and the stream (nested usings are OK).